# Migration HIBERNATE 2 to HIBERNATE 3: net.sf.hibernate.tool.hbm2java.FinderRenderer

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, jpos

I've read https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide30 and much extra information on the web, and I couldn't find anything related to this. There is no spec anywhere.
What I would like to know, is if there is a way to achieve in (hibernate3 -> org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask) what I did using (hibernate2 -> net.sf.hibernate.tool.hbm2java.FinderRenderer).

I need to migrate from Hibernate2 to Hibernate3, and it was going good until I reached some *finder.java which were generated by Hibernate2. Then, I'm trying to do the same using Hibernate3, but I find no way to do it.

I'm using jpos, so before Hibernate3, *Finder.java pojos where generated by _codegen.xml file located in eecore module. _codegen.xml looks like this:

```
<codegen>
  <generate renderer="net.sf.hibernate.tool.hbm2java.BasicRenderer"/> 
  <generate suffix="Finder" renderer="net.sf.hibernate.tool.hbm2java.FinderRenderer"/> 
</codegen>
```

Does anyone know how to do that, or at least, what happened with this functionality in hibernate3?